# src value in iframe not change at runtime

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

In my application I want to change the src value of iframe on click of radio button But when I try to do that I got error as:

> ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference

Here is my html code as:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

                    <input id="aaa" name="exch_type" type="radio" value="AAA" checked="checked"/>
                    <label for="aaa" style="width: 125px;">AAA</label>

                    <input id="bbb" name="exch_type" type="radio" value="BBB" />
                    <label for="bbb" style="width: 125px;">BBB</label>
                </fieldset>

            </div>                  

        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <iframe name = "chartId" id = "chartId" src="http://myDomain/chts/mobile.asp?Scrip=AAA&Exchange=XXX&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300" scrolling="yes"></iframe> 
        </div>
```

And click function as

```
$('input[name=exch_type]').change(function()
    {
        var radio_val = $('input[name=exch_type]:checked').val();

        if (radio_val=="AAA")
        {

            $("#chartId").attr("src") = "http://myDomain/charts/mobilechart.asp?Scrip=AAAIND&Exchange=NSE&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300";

        }

        else if (radio_val=="BBB")
        {

            $("#chartId").attr("src") = "http://myDomain/charts/mobilechart.asp?Scrip=BBBIND&Exchange=NSE&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300";
        }
        //alert('Radio Value: '+radio_val);
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tested but, note a bad assignment:

```
$("#chartId").attr("src") = src="http://myDomain/chts/mobile.asp?Scrip=AAA&Exchange=XXX&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300";
```

instead of:

```
$("#chartId").attr("src", "http://myDomain/chts/mobile.asp?Scrip=AAA&Exchange=XXX&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300");
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$("#chartId").attr("src", "http://myDomain/chts/mobile.asp?Scrip=AAA&Exchange=XXX&ChartType=I&Hg=150&Wd=300");
```